# Evaluate $\sum_{\sigma} (2\pi i)^{-n}\oint \frac{f_{\sigma(1)}(u)\dots f_{\sigma_n(1)}(u)}{(u_2 - u_1)\dots (u_n - u_{n-1})}du_1\dots du_n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

In a probability theory paper I found this rather pleasant result:

> **Theorem 4.1** Let $n \geq 2$ and $f_1, \dots, f_n : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be meromorphic with possible poles at $\{ \mathfrak{p}_1, \dots, \mathfrak{p}_n \} $ Then we have identity
>   $$ \sum_{\sigma \in S^{cyc}(n)} \frac{1}{(2\pi \mathbf{i})^n }\oint \dots \oint  \frac{f_{\sigma(1)}(u_1)\dots f_{\sigma_n(n)}(u_n)  }{(u_2 - u_1)\dots (u_n - u_{n-1})}\;du_1 \dots du_n
> = \frac{1}{2\pi \mathbf{i} }\oint f_1(u)\dots f_n(u) du $$

It is proven with a lengthy induction process.  The authors obtain the result they needed.  I wondered if there is more conceptual argument (perhaps using divisors) and could this be generalized beyond cyclic permutations.

- [Interlacing adjacent levels of β-Jacobi corners processes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.02321) Vadim Gorin, Lingfu Zhang

Is there a name for when contour integrals simplify under permutation group action in this way?

Comment: Just a comment: I encountered this too, see Lemma 7 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00342. Though not lengthy, the proof I give there is still by induction.

Comment: I would add that $S^{cyc}$ means the cyclic subgroup of $S_n$ generated by a long cycle.

Comment: Hope I wrote it correctly now. Usually they just wrote $\Sigma_{cyc}$ as you might see in Olympiad. These integral identities were convenient as they evaluated $n$-point correlations.

Comment: There should be $\sigma$ in the denominator too, else we get something wrong for $n=2$ (the difference $u_2-u_1$ does not cancel)

Comment: I do not understand what the identity is already for $n=2$. If the integrand is $(f_1(u_1)f_2(u_2)-f_1(u_2)f_2(u_1))/(u_2-u_1)$, the identity does not hold: for pairs $(f_1,f_2)=(f,1)$ and $(f_1,f_2)=(1,f)$ the values of the integral have opposite sign